# XSL-FOで下線の色を変更する

Tags: xsl, xsl-fo, 組版

XSL-FOではで文字に下線をひくことができますが、文字色と下線の色を異なる色にする方法はありますか？

CSSには、text-decoration-color がありますが XSL-FOにそれは見つかりませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSL勧告で規定されていない場合、ベンダーの拡張で実現されている場合があります．

例） AH Formatterの場合

http://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v65/ahf-ext.html#text-decoration

の `axf:text-line-color` が該当します．

Comment: やはりFOの仕様にはない、ということで宜しいでしょうか？

Comment: ありません．XSL 1.1は2006年12月5日に勧告になりました．当時は必要な機能ではなかったのでしょう．

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決済みといたします。